# Are Update/Delete/Insert on the LINQ Roadmap?

Tags: sql, linq, insert, sql-update

Like SQL, LINQ is a great way to retrieve data from various sources, but to date I haven't heard anyone talking about the other elements that SQL provides, specifically update/insert/delete. The various DLinq providers all offer their own mechanisms, but it seems like at some point modification of a data source would become part of the language extension that LINQ represents. Has anyone seen any articles or discussions about this step in LINQ's evolution?

Much appreciated!

Comment: As a clarification, I'm talking about update as part of the language, not through a provider specific method in DataContext/Session/Collection, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Linq targets two interfaces, `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>`.

Think about how a delete operation would be performed against an `IEnumerable<T>`.

How do you delete things from `Enumerable.Range(0, 5)` ?

Comment: You took the words out of my mouth. LinqToObjects cannot support mutable operations "by design".

Comment: That is a good point, but it only covers Linq as it exists now. Again I'm drawn to the idea of SQL where query is just one part of a complete data retrieval & modification language. Linq to date is only a data retrieval language and it seems like at some point additional interfaces and language extensions would be added to update diverse sets of data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're getting at, this is supported in [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386931.aspx).

Comment: Yup, each specific LINQ provider offers its own version of how to update, insert, and delete. My question is why develop a "universal language" for reading and ten independent methods for writing. If SQL was "read only" and you had to go to a different lanuage/framwork to write, it probably wouldn't have survived this long.

Answer (score 0):

Updates, insertions and deletions are generally a much easier problem than doing queries (essentially a find operation).

If you are referring to generic collections rather than databases, you make a method call like Insert or Add to add an item, and Delete or Remove to remove an item.  To change an item, generally you just manipulate the item directly.

Comment: I agree that they are different problems to solve, but generally you use them together (find this object, change it's color to "red"). And since you can query data from various sources (databases, lists) in one common way, why not updating them also? Like, wouldn't this be nice:

update myListOrXmlOrDataBase
set color = "red"
where name = "tomato";